# element.style.display is not what rendered in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Probably a duplicate question but can not find the answer.

element.style.display is not what rendered in the browser.

Instead of returning the actual value (ie. block or inline etc), it returns empty. Tested in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

How do I get the actual rendered value?

```js
function displayStyle(aEvent) {
aEvent.target.textContent=aEvent.target.style.display;
}
window.onload = function() { 
var  top_array = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
for(var i = 0; i <  top_array.length; i++)
{
   top_array[i].addEventListener("click", displayStyle, false);
}
}
```

```css
.top{
background-color:#FFF8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">top (click it and it will disappear because its style.display is empty)</div>
```

Comment: `HTMLElement.style` represents only the element's **inline** style attribute (i.e. the `style="display: ..."` in the html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS styles are not available to JavaScript *unless* they have been formerly set in JavaScript or they have been hardcoded as inline styles.

Use **[getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** instead:

```js
function displayStyle(aEvent) {
  var target = aEvent.target;
  target.textContent = window.getComputedStyle(target).getPropertyValue('display');
}

window.onload = function() {
  var top_array = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
  for (var i = 0; i < top_array.length; i++) {
    top_array[i].addEventListener("click", displayStyle, false);
  }
}
```

```css
.top {
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">top (click it and it will now show "block" since we're getting its computed style.)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works if you set it directly in `style` attribute:

```js
function displayStyle(aEvent) {
aEvent.target.textContent=aEvent.target.style.display;
}
window.onload = function() { 
var  top_array = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
for(var i = 0; i <  top_array.length; i++)
{
   top_array[i].addEventListener("click", displayStyle, false);
}
}
```

```css
.top{
background-color:#FFF8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="top" style="display: block;">top (click it and it will disappear because its style.display is empty)</div>
```

Obs.: setting it on CSS also doesn't work.

<strike>I still don't know why, anyway.</strike>

Now I know, thanks to [Rick Hitchcock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43124933/3136474).